# How can I toggle component in datatemplate, when I select an item?

Tags: c#, xamarin, collectionview

I have a CollectionView in my page, which displays items. I need to toggle visual indicator (checkmark), that item is selected. The checkmark should be stylized, but I haven't done it, I only tried with BoxView. Nothing reasonable seems to work.

I have tried setting a flag in my Model if item is selected and then reload collection, but this is a very bad approach, that also consumes a lot of resources. I just need a toggle, that will appear on item click and dissappear on second one.

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding price, Converter={StaticResource Price}}" Style="{StaticResource PriceLabel}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<Label Text="{Binding name}" Style="{StaticResource CommonLabel}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<!-- Somehow change this-->
 <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Disired result should look like [this](https://prnt.sc/pt9rrx) but that's another part of the story

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, if you want to BoxView to display selected or unselected for Collectionview item, I suggest you can use one property to bind BoxView IsVisible, I do one sample that you can take a look:

Model:

```
public class Model:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _DisplayName;

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return _DisplayName; }
        set
        {
            _DisplayName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DisplayName");
        }
    }
    private bool _selected;

    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return _selected; }
        set
        {
            _selected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }

}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class collectionviewmodel:ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Items { get; set; }


    public collectionviewmodel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        Items.Add(new Model() { DisplayName = "AAA", Selected = false });
        Items.Add(new Model() { DisplayName = "BBB", Selected = false });
        Items.Add(new Model() { DisplayName = "CCC", Selected = false });
        Items.Add(new Model() { DisplayName = "DDD", Selected = false });
        Items.Add(new Model() { DisplayName = "EEE", Selected = false });


    }       
}
```

ContentPage:

```
  <CollectionView
            x:Name="list1"
            ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            SelectionChanged="List1_SelectionChanged"
            SelectionMode="Single">

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <Label
                            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                            Text="{Binding DisplayName}"
                            TextColor="Fuchsia" />
                        <BoxView
                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                            IsVisible="{Binding Selected}"
                            Color="Fuchsia" />
                    </StackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

public Page23 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.BindingContext = new collectionviewmodel();
    }
```

The screenshot like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me! I didn't copy the code exactly, googled some thigs, but it works! Everyday I learn something new, today I learned about INotifyPropertyChanged :)

Answer (score 0):

What I did understand

you are trying to display an indicator on an item when it's selected, and only one item can be selected at the same time

So you need to set the SelectionMode to Single in your CollectionView, so only one item can be selected at a time

then you can display the indicator on the selected item and hide it on the previous one using OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged

you can find more details here [Xamarin-Collectionview-Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection)